# In ssh, what is the id_rsa_opay file?

Tags: ssh

I set up an rsa key in .ssh on an IBM iSeries(V7R4) using OpenSSH_8.0p1.  Running `ssh -vT git@github.com`.  I get

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa_opay
```

There is no such file. There is ".ssh/id_rsa".  The signon is failing because of this. Any ideas about what is going on here?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; where knowing the *software stack* involved is the starting point.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Your version details only match non-Ubuntu products, or EOL releases of Ubuntu that aren't on-topic here*

Comment: hmmm?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76626559/ssh-seems-to-be-trying-to-use-a-ssh-rsa-opay-file-for-publickey-authentication  why crosspost?

Comment: Can you add the content of "~/.ssh/config" to the question? Or as we can see from the crosspost, the content of "/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/SC1/OpenSSH/etc/ssh_config" is needed in the question.